# Use Mitt in Vue2 to replace this.$root.on/off

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Moving away from `this.$root.$on` and `this.$root.$off`
Docs say to use `mitt` but not working for Vue2?

Component One

```js
mounted() {
  emitter.on('doThis', (id) => this.doThis(id));
}
destroyed() {
  emitter.off('doThis', (id) => this.doThis(id))
}
methods: {
  doThis(id) {
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

```js
Component Two
handleClick() {
  emitter.emit('doThis', this.item.id);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the source code

Comment: Updated in original

Comment: What doesn't work? How are these components related? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve